# Как лучше загружать и использовать вертексные буфферы?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, directx-11

Как мне стоит рисовать вершинные буферы в D3D11? У меня есть .obj файл, в котором есть точки, нормали, и индексы, нормалей значительно больше чем точек. Так вот, мне лучше создавать большой буффер с вертексами, состоящими из нормалей и координат и рисовать с помощью `pContext->Draw();` или же загрузить только уникальные точки и рисовать их по индексам с помощью `pContext->DrawIndexed()`? Если использовать второй вариант, то как мне передавать нормали?